# Calling an AJAX function declared as a VAR, using Applescript

Tags: javascript, ajax, applescript

I am trying to run a javascript code inside a page using Applescript.

The AJAX function was declared in javascript using something like this

```
var myFunction = function () {
  // bla bla... here goes the code...
}
```

I have tried this in Applescript:

```
do JavaScript "document.myFunction()"
```

but the code is not running.

any clues? thanks.

Comment: I don't think the function is actually a child object of the document. Have you tried other scopes, like `myFunction()`, `window.myFunction()`, or `document.getElementById("head")[0].myFunction()`?

Comment: I have tried this 3 scopes and still not running...

Comment: Just do 'do JavaScript "myFunction()"' in document 1'

Comment: @fireshadow52 nothing happens. The function is created as a var. Are you sure doing this will run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are created as properties of the [global object](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-10.html#a-10.1.5) (`window`, for web browsers). Thus `window.myFunction` would be the proper reference. However, you don't need to specify the global object.

The key is that you must specify in AppleScript the target tab or document. For example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "myFunction()" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```